# Permission denied while creating a new laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, installation

i was trying to create a new laravel project using the laravel command `laravel new project_name`
this gives an error

```
Crafting application...
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\xampp\htdocs/wub/server.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Users\Fathi\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\laravel\installer\src\NewCommand.php on line 151

Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\xampp\htdocs/wub/server.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Users\Fathi\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\laravel\installer\src\NewCommand.php on line 151
You should verify that the "storage" and "bootstrap/cache" directories are writable.
Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\xampp\htdocs\wub
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

i am using a windows computer

Comment: which user own your `C:\xampp\htdocs\wub` file?

Comment: use composer and follow this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation

Comment: the administrator owns the file

Comment: That's the problem, he shouldn't.

Comment: Agreed with @AmmarAli try the full command